# Exchange 2010 only see internal .lan addresses

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

Network:
Very basic home office for my software business. 2 Users

2 servers - 
Server 1: DC
Server 2008
Just has AD
able to ping and rdp to other servers from laptop

Server 2: Mail
Server 2008 R2
Exchange Server 2010

When I look at my properties for my e-mail address it shows name@domain.lan, insead of name@domain.com.

I can send e-mails internally to the same address and to the other AD address, but cannot send anything external nor can I receive anything externally. I have a static ip business line to support the network.

Thanks, I'm very new at all of this

Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the default email address policy. Easiest way to do this is through Exchange Management Console. Open up Organization Configuration. Then Hub Transport. Click on the Email Address Policies tab. Click on "New email address policy" in the right column. Give it any name, no condition, add the email address format.

If you missed this, you probably missed some other important things to establish mail flow. You should probably work through this document:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125262.aspx?v=14.0.702.0&t=exchgf1

Comment: And I'd call _that_ smarter than me. :)

Comment: That was great, very detailed and 100% correct, it worked great. I'm going to read over the link to see if I missed anything else.

Thanks for the fast response!